# Exposing a new type to python at run time

Tags: python, c, module, runtime, python-extensions

I have gone through and defined my new types, stored them in a pytypeobject and called the following functions (after initializing the interpreter):

PyType_Ready(); //this takes my defined typed

PyModule_AddObject(); //this adds the defined type to a module I created using
                      PyModule_Create();

Now when I try to use the type I have defined the interpreter says it doesn't exist so I am assuming there is another step that must be taken in order to add a type at run time or there is some other set of steps I must take to achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Python Syntax Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Bound
ImportError: No module named Bound
```

Test script contents:

```
import Bound
l = Bound.Foo()
```

Bound is the name I defined the module, and Foo is the type I am trying to define, for testing purposes.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you got.

Comment: Also indicate the exact syntax you are trying to use to access the type.

Comment: Or provide *some* kind of debugging information :P

Comment: I added debug info, but I don't see how it helps. Either you know how to add user defined types to python at run-time or you don't. The information I provided should be enough for someone who knows how to do this.

Comment: @Dane: "No module named Bound" means it's not seeing your compiled module at all. That's before it even tries to look for `Foo`. So you need to work out producing a module that you can import first.

Comment: @Thomas: I know it isn't seeing the module at all. That is the question, what step do I need to take to actually expose my module I've created at run-time to the interpreter.

Comment: @Dane: I'm not sure I quite follow what you're trying to do, but you probably want to have a look at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html and PEP 302.

Comment: I am trying to expose user defined C++ classes to python at run-time.
I have taken all the steps shown in the python documentation to create a new type, ready it, create a module, add the object to the module, BUT there is another step needed to expose it to the interpreter AT run-time. Not creating a type, module, then compiling. It is create type, module, expose. I just don't know how to accomplish the last step.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what I needed to do, I had to call a function before `Py_Initialize`,

```
PyImport_AppendInittab( ModuleName, ModuleInitFunction );
```

This adds the module name to the python module dictionary so when you call `import ModuleName`, if it is for the first time it will call the `ModuleInitFunction` ( which I had, but wasn't using in the proper place ), which creates the module. Now after a module is created you can then proceed to add types to it at run-time which is what I do.

Right now I can successfully bind user defined C++ classes to python at run-time, then use them in a script in our Game Engine. Right now I am working out run-time kinks, but it should be up and running within the next few days. Anyways if anyone else ever decides to embed python into a game engine for scripting I'm sure I can help.